# RunTime Error Code 3709: Running SQL Query from file and paste data into spreadsheet

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to obtain data from a SQL Database by running a query that's saved in a folder.

every time I run the code I get a "runtime error 3709 - the connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context.

anyone have any ideas why or where I'm going wrong?

please see below for the codes I'm using. The code bugs out in the GetQueryResults Sub Route and highlights RST.Open.

**SqlQuery Module**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Open_QueryFile()

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim TS As Scripting.TextStream
Dim QueryString As String


Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile("R:\ORBIT\Tomas\SQL\SQLQuery - SO Dashboard.sql")

QueryString = TS.ReadAll
 
TS.Close

'MsgBox QueryString

GetQueryResults QueryString

End Sub


Sub GetQueryResults(SQLString As String)

Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

Call openConnection

Set rst.ActiveConnection = cn

  Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    rst.Source = SQLString
    rst.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    rst.LockType = adLockReadOnly
    rst.Open
        
    WriteResultstoSheet rst
          
End Sub


Sub WriteResultstoSheet(ResultSet As ADODB.Recordset)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets.Add

ws.Select
ws.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset ResultSet

Call closeConnection

End Sub
```

**DbConnection Module**

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Public Const ORBITServerLocation             As String = "Server=**-*******-**;Database=****;Trusted_Connection=yes;"

Public cn                               As Object
Public rst                              As Object
Public sSQL                             As String
    
Public Const adUseClient                As Integer = 3
Public Const adModeReadWrite            As Integer = 3
Public Const adModeRead                 As Integer = 1
Public Const adLockOptimistic           As Integer = 3
Public Const adOpenForwardOnly          As Integer = 0
Public Const adStateOpen                As Integer = 1
Public Const adLockBatchOptimistic      As Integer = 4
Sub openConnection()
    
    If cn Is Nothing Then
        Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    End If
    If (cn.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then
        cn.Close
    End If
    cn.Provider = "sqloledb"
    cn.Mode = adModeRead
    cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    cn.CommandTimeout = 600
    cn.Open ORBITServerLocation
    
End Sub


Sub closeConnection()
    If Not cn Is Nothing Then
        If (cn.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then
            cn.Close
        End If
    End If
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Did I miss where you assigned the connection to the recordset?

Comment: Hi Rory, if I'm honest I'm a complete amateur at this so I've been trying to decipher examples online to make it fit for myself. perhaps that's where I'm going wrong and its missing completely? any suggestions?

Comment: You can remove your `cnn` variable since you don't do anything with it, then add `set rst.connection = cn` before you open the recordset.

Comment: i've just tried that with the compile error on ".connection" (Method or data member not found.

Comment: Sorry - that should have been `activeconnection` not just `connection`

Comment: Sorry still no luck, now getting  Runtime error '91':

Comment: Needs to be **after** the `set rst = New ADODB.Recordset` line.

Comment: thats the hammer! thanks rory!